# Generation of random Matrix with Real eigen values

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, algorithms, matrix

does anyone know any matlab algorithm that can help me generate a random matrix with REAL EIGEN values?
Thanks.

Comment: What is your definitions of "random matrix"? If you want some distribution over all matrices with real eigenvalues this is hard. If you want a distribution over all possible real eigenvalues you could do something as simple as a diagonal matrix with random entries on the diagonal.

Answer (score 6):

You don't mention what kind of distribution you want for the entries of the random matrix, so the simplest recipe that I can think of is to first create a random $n \times n$ matrix $\mathtt{A}$ and to then obtain $\mathtt{B} = \frac{1}{2} ( \mathtt{A} + \mathtt{A}^{\mathtt{T}} )$.  That gives you a symmetric matrix $\mathtt{B}$ with random entries.  Since symmetric matrices have real eigenvalues, the matrix $\mathtt{B}$ will satisfy your requirement.

Matlab code:

```
A = rand(n)
B = 0.5 * (A + transpose(A))
```

Here's another approach, building on [Bill Barth's answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/20840/15). First, create a random diagonal matrix $\mathtt{D}$, then obtain a random orthogonal matrix $\mathtt{Q}$ and, finally, compute the similarity transformation $\mathtt{B} = \mathtt{Q} \, \mathtt{D} \, \mathtt{Q}^{\mathtt{T}}$.  The matrix $\mathtt{B}$ will have the same eigenvalues as $\mathtt{D}$ but will not be diagonal in general.  A simple way to come up with a random orthogonal matrix $\mathtt{Q}$ is to compute the QR decomposition of a random matrix.

Matlab code:

```
D = diag(rand(n, 1))
[Q ~] = qr(rand(n))
B = Q * D * transpose(Q)
```

Comment: Wonderful. I think my problem has been solved by your answer. You guys are too awesome. Thanks

Comment: Which is the answer I should have been able to come up with. Nice.

Comment: @user1144656 If this answer solved your problem, you should accept it!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify the eigenvalues, then you can just put them on the diagonal of an otherwise empty matrix.